# Typical mistake: xspace is always looking forwards, never backwards

Tags: biblatex, macros, delimiters, ifthenelse

How could we explain the difference between those two outputs, where the second one features `}` just after `\xspace`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\coolxspaceunprotected}{\ifhmode\unskip\xspace\fi}
\newcommand{\coolxspaceprotected}{{\ifhmode\unskip\xspace\fi}} % How to avoid the braces?

\newcommand{\spacetciteunprotected}{\coolxspaceunprotected\textcite}
\newcommand{\spacetciteprotected}{\coolxspaceprotected\textcite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
    @book{smith96,
        author = {Smith, Adam},
        year = {1996},
        title = {Economy},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

\section{\spacetciteunprotected{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}

\section{\spacetciteprotected{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the role of `\xspace` here? Just remove it.

Comment: Inside sentences, I want automatic spacing before the citation.

Comment: @egreg beat me to it but xspace is doing absolutely nothing here

Comment: You're *removing* a space

Comment: xspace only has any possible use as the last token in a definition. Here you use it before  `}` or before `\textcite` so it does no good at all, it just adds a space, slowly.

Comment: remove `\xspace` use `\ifhmode\unskip\space\fi`

Comment: as I say use `\space` not `\xspace` (and use `\DeclareRobustCommand` so your command is safe in `\section`

Comment: but why let xspace trying to figure out what is following when you know it already?  xspace doesn't look back, it looks forward.

Comment: @egreg You are right, I understand why now.

Comment: @Ulrike It took me some reflection but I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the TO suggests to do so in the last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Your main problem is you are adding a space in `hmode`, but just after
a parindent (or sec number) box you are in `hmode` but do not want a space. `\xspace` is not helping here. You want to look *back* not forwards, this avoids adding a space after a `hbox` (node type 1) so it would add a space after a character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareRobustCommand\coolspaceunprotected{%
\ifhmode\ifnum\lastnodetype=1 \else\unskip\unskip\space
\fi\fi}


\DeclareRobustCommand\spacetciteunprotected{\coolspaceunprotected\textcite}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
    @book{smith96,
        author = {Smith, Adam},
        year = {1996},
        title = {Economy},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\spacetciteunprotected{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}
a

\section{\textcite{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}
b
\section{Foo,\spacetciteunprotected{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}
c

\section{Foo,\textcite{smith96} and the blob hypothesis}
d

\end{document}
```

Comment: hasn't the `filecontents` package been integrated to the kernel?

Comment: @Udi I'll remove it, thanks.

Comment: @UdiFogiel yes,

Comment: @VincentKrebs your second one had `\xspace}` so xspace will never add a space so you got no space, it is as if you just had unskip

Comment: Oh I see, the brace is telling `\xspace` that there is nothing after it so it does not add a space. So it had nothing to do with great LaTeX principles after all, just with a silly mistake of mine!

Comment: @VincentKrebs exactly, which is why it is never useful to use xspace except as the last token.if you know what token follows xspace you know it will always add a space or always do nothing, either way you can replace it by space or nothing

Comment: Yes I got it, this is what Ulrike was saying. I usually use `\unskip\xspace` at the end of macros.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks to `\DeclareRobustCommand`, the space is not ignored in the TOC! :)

Comment: @VincentKrebs certainly it would need to be robust to do _anything_ in the toc, if it's doing the wrong thing I'll adjust

Comment: @VincentKrebs looks OK to me, I extended the example, it adds space just after the `,` in section 3, in both main heading and toc

Comment: I know it works yes, I checked ;) Thank you very much for your help. This `\coolspace` is also very useful for abbreviations (such as *vs.*, which I store as a command so that I do not have to worry about the dot being regarded as a `.\@`, with the right space factor).